# Python Mechanize Ignore Control says ReadOnly

Tags: python, forms, urllib2, mechanize

I have trying to submit a form using mechanize.

here my form structure.

```
<form class="pagin fr" name="formPage" action="/fetdata" id="topPagin" method="POST">

 <input id="dataicn" name="clust" value="" type="hidden"> 

 <input name="serialid" value="123" type="hidden">

 <button class="dir pgNext" type="button" name="pageNo" value=" 2"=""> &gt; </button>
</form>
```

When I try to see the controls of this form I get .

```
  <HiddenControl(clust=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(serialid=123) (readonly)>
  <IgnoreControl(pageNo=<None>)>>
```

I have to change the PageNo to submit the form, So I have changed the pageno in different ways, that is disabling the button and setting read only but it says always .

```
  AttributeError: control 'pageNo' is ignored, hence read-only


        pagecontrol3 = br_n.form.find_control("pageNo")
        pagecontrol3.readonly = False
        pagecontrol3.disabled = False
        pagecontrol3.disabled = True
        pagecontrol3.value = pageNo
```

Please give me the solution for this.